# Filter column with numeric value, create new column

Tags: ms-access-2010, ssms, sql-server-express

I think the title makes this sound possibly more difficult then it is.

Basically, I have a Table called Orders. 18 Columns.

The PK is called ORDERID(Nvarchar).

The problem child is a field called CustomerID(nvarchar). Prior to my assignment, this field use to be populated with raw customer information(Customer1, Customer 2 etc.) However, sometime ago, it was decided to insert just the number corresponding to the customer from the customer table and perform the lookup at the front end.  The records that have the raw customer data are existent in the customer table but the lookup won't work when it tries to parse the CustomerID to the customer table, when the text is present. It results in blank fields on the front end.

```
OrderID(PK) Inquiry# CustomerID
Z1          I1       Customer1 (Look up on front end does not work)
Z2          I2       23        (Look up on front end works)
```

A couple foreseeable solutions.

1. Repalce old customerID with the corresponding customer number
2. Modify query on frontend to only show records that were created after the change to customerID(text -> #) Then push a new front end to everyone(around 80 employees)
3. Extract the records that have a text value instead of a number and create a new table called something like dbo.OldOrders Again I'd have to push a new front end.

Ideally I'd like to the accomplish the first solution if at all possible.

Anyone have any advisement?

Comment: In ssms I just checked how many records aren't numeric. 


`where ISNUMERIC([CustomerID])<>1;`

7467 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a view that converts it into a number and then pull from there?